# How long will Swiffy Run Times Be Supported?

Tags: swiffy

Recently Google announced that announced that they are transitioning all of our display ads to HTML5 and sun setting Swiffy.

Google also wrote that they "will continue to serve the Swiffy runtimes, so any files you convert before the sunset date will continue to play"

Can anyone tell me for how long Google will continue to serve the Swiffy runtimes?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming related issues?

Comment: It is related to Swiffy and Google's recent announcement not to support it.  i just wanted to know how long the runtimes wil be served.

Comment: Seems not to be a direct programming issue.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know the answer would you?

Comment: No sorry. I saw your post and clicked out of curiosity. Never heard of swiffy

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere that they have specified how long, but if you have an extra 100k in file size to spare you could always download the runtime .js file and include it with your local files.

The real bummer is that they are shutting the converter down that enabled the Flash swiffy extension to work.  Now that will be bricked.

Comment: I would agree with forrex, get the runtime .js file and put it in your project if you can?  I've been doing this for a while and now I'm glad I did.  The fact the converter has been removed has presented me with a real headache.  I have hundreds of Flash animations that I'll now need to manually re-write.  Swiffy was a great tool and I would have happily paid for it.  Shame it's been shelved.